# Unable to use value.sort function in my pipe.ts

Tags: arrays, angular, object, pipe, angular7

I'm displaying the data from the backend api through a service and now I want to filter the data that is being displayed. So, I created a pipe but it's throwing an error that `value.sort is not a function`. Is it because that my data is an object and not an array? Can someone help me with this?

I've reproduced the problem here
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-multi-db67lv)

**sort.pipe.ts**

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
 name: 'sort',
 pure: false
  })
 export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(value: any[], criteria: SortCriteria): any[] {
console.log('Piped');
console.log(value);
if (!value || !criteria)
  return value;

let p: string = criteria.property;

let sortFn:(a: any, b: any) => any = (a, b) => {
  let value: number = 0;
  if (a[p] === undefined) value = -1;
  else if (b[p] === undefined) value = 1;
  else value = a[p] > b[p] ? 1 : (b[p] > a[p] ? -1 : 0);
  return criteria.descending ? (value * -1) : value;
};

value.sort(sortFn);
return value;
  }

  }

 export interface SortCriteria {
 property: string;
 descending?: boolean;
  }
```

Comment: "Is it because that my data is an object?" Yes

Comment: @ritaj is there any work around this?

Comment: How would you sort an object? What does that even mean?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because `value` is a BehaviorSubject in your code. You need to extract value(which is an array in your case) in it and then call `sort` on it. So change the code like this and it should work:

`value.getValue().sort(sortFn);`

Comment: @Nijoo Did you try changing that to `Observable<any>`?